# Python code retrieve empty list when analyzing terms of frequencies using twitter APIs

Tags: python, api, for-loop, counter, tweepy

the result when I run the analysis to the tweets comes empty as below
there is nothing wrong with the code
but the result is an empty list!

result is below
[]

```
import re
import operator
import json
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import bigrams
import string
from collections import defaultdict
import sys
com = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
fname = '/content/covid19.json'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
  count_all = Counter()
  for line in f.readlines():
    if line.startswith('{'):
      tweet = json.loads(line)
      terms_only = [term for term in preprocess(tweet['text']) if term not in stop and not term.startswith(('@', '#'))]
      count_all.update(terms_only)
print(count_all.most_common(5))
```

Comment: where is the empty list? in `terms_only`?

Comment: when i run the code i got an empty list

Comment: in which variable?